# WebAssembly Blazor Android support

Tags: blazor, webassembly

How does Blazor WebAssembly works on Android phone for example.

For other browsers it need to run on .dotnet runtime of the client machines which makes sense if the client machine have .net core version running on their machine.

The technology in preview but when we talk about Android how will this code work on them. will it require .net core to be installed on andriod? ARM edition of .net core ???

actually on MS documentation .net core does not list Android as support OS in the first place.

It seems it uses MONO as webassembly which can run .net core. So does it eventually support andriod?

source: Microsoft:
Q: How can you run .NET in a web browser?
Running .NET in the browser is made possible by a relatively new standardized web technology called WebAssembly. WebAssembly is a "portable, size- and load-time-efficient format suitable for compilation to the web." Code compiled to WebAssembly can run in any browser at native speeds. To run .NET binaries in a web browser we use a .NET runtime (specifically Mono) that has been compiled to WebAssembly.
source link: https://github.com/dotnet/blazor/wiki/FAQ

Any insights??

Comment: Not what you're asking directly, but related so look at Uno https://platform.uno/how-it-works/

Comment: WebAssembly runs in the browser and doesn't need .NET Core. Blazor is MS tech that compiles to WebAssembly.

Comment: MS has some plan (not committed) to integrate blazer with Xamarin https://itnext.io/blazor-and-native-mobile-apps-9177c5a6488b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

responded by MS team on their github site: 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20770

its there and now supported through webassembly version of .net core

still have to tryout though.

Update:
More updated added by ms:
 Hi @shahidroofi. Blazor WebAssembly apps use a WebAssembly implementation of the Mono IL interpreter instead of .NET Core, so the .NET Core docs are still technically correct. It's a bit confusing right now, because there are multiple different .NET implementations that make up the .NET ecosystem currently. In .NET 5 this should all get cleaned up and unified.